# Find tag by attribute and read all his children

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
<Product productName="testProduct1">
    <Fields>
        <Field name="Stack" />
        <Field name="Overflow" />
    </Fields>
    <AnotherFields>
        <Field name="Test" />
    </AnotherFields>
</Product>
<Product productName="testProduct">
    <Fields>
        <Field name="StackOverflow" />
    </Fields>
</Product>
</Products>
```

And want to read all the child tags of `product` which has exclusive value of attribute `productName`, all other tags is want to skip.

And here is my java code I am stuck:

```
public void mainParser(XmlResourceParser configXML, String productNameParameter)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int eventType = -1; 
    String strName, productName;

    while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {

            strName = configXML.getName();

            if (strName.equals("Product")) {
                if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {

                    productName = configXML.getAttributeValue(null, "productName");

                    if (productName.equals(productNameParameter)) {
                        eventType = configXML.next();

                        //here is the problem

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        eventType = configXML.next();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest only checking the event types on one level rather than nested loops and using boolean flags to indicate that you are inside your specific "Product" element:

```
boolean foundIt = false;
while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    strName = configXML.getName();

    if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
        if (!foundIt && strName.equals("Product")) {
            productName = configXML.getAttributeValue(null, "productName");

            if (productName.equals(productNameParameter)) {
                foundIt = true;
            }
        }
        else if (foundIt) {
            // Children
        }
    }
    else if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.END_TAG) {
        if (foundIt && strName.equals("Product")) {
            foundIt = false;
            return; // You've found what you want, leave method
        }
    }

    eventType = configXML.next();
}
```

Now you won't be calling `configXML.next()` or checking the `eventType` in multiple places, which could easily get confusing.  Notice that once `foundIt` is true we stop looking for "Product" tags and begin reading every new element by default.  Finally when you read the "Product"'s end tag stop everything.